# asterisk - write plugin to "catch" voice stream

Tags: audio, asterisk, voip, freepbx

I have installed Asterisk and FreePBX on a server. I have set up some extensions for testing and I have configured voicemail for these. I have discovered that voice mail files gets stored in `/var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/(EXTENSION)/tmp/(TMPFILE).wav`
and that they are later moved to `/var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/(EXTENSION)/INBOX/msg####.wav`

I want to stream the voice data to another server in real time so that the server can start processing of the data. That is I want to start streaming the data as soon as a call is received by Asterisk and I do not want to wait for the hang up before sending the sound.

I am looking for how to hook into Asterisk to get hold of the voice data. I have a few ideas so far:

1) Regularly check the /tmp directories for new files and start reading them as soon as they are available. But the file names are random and I also want to find out who is calling for example. Seem like a dead end. Files might also get stuck if I read them while Asterisk tries to move them?

2) Maybe I could write a plugin for Asterisk that can pick up the files in the right step of the process. If so, what do I need to write such a plugin and how can I configure it to get access to the voice data as soon as the voice mail module picks up the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use EAGI program which able get sound from channel #3.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+EAGI

You also can do c/c++ app for asterisk which will do streamming(see source code in apps/ folder for examples)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This sounds spot on. EAGI looks straight forward and I also found a good example. But can I config the EAGI script to be used for all incoming calls? And can I receive the phone number in EAGI?

Comment: Please read more about AGI. Sure you can control all calls via AGI. But anyway you need read asterisk book first.

Comment: I managed to get a solution working. It was quite straight forward, however the audio quality is really really bad. I have searched for a way to increase it. Is it possible? If not I think I need to find another solution...

Comment: sorry, can say nothing about. try record stream and compare with audio you have. most likly you just do bad realization or used VPS.

Comment: So there is no way to increase the samplerate?

Comment: sample rate 8khz. all voip work with that. you can use 16khz(wideband codecs),but it will be re-sampled when you call POTS lines. so no sence. EAGI will resample to 8khz too, just becuase it have be compatible with older scripts.

Comment: Interesting, is there any way I can extract the 16khz version to a file for example? Then I could have AGI set upp a fifo file and let Asterisk write to that file and I can then ignore file descriptor 3? Or maybe I am totally out of luck? Would it be simple to patch Asterisk to do this if it is not available by default?

Comment: You can record narrowband stream to file, no problem in that.But you can't get narrowband from PSTN. Google by "g722+asterisk". I can't say if patch c/c++ code simple for you or not,sorry

Comment: I dont use PSTN at all so that is no problem. If I record to a file using AGI. How can I specify a better quality than the default? Because recordings in asterisk also use 8khz by default, right?

Comment: You can't change format for EAGI. You should create special c/c++ app for do that.

Comment: Jens, did you find a solution for the quality issue here with Asterisk?  I am about to embark on the same journey.